# PYInstaller and Eel not recompiling cleanly

Tags: javascript, python, windows, pyinstaller, eel

I am using a package called [Eel](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel/) to build desktop GUI applications. I am trying to create an executable on windows 11 with the built in command that uses PYInstaller to create an executable.

```bash
python -m eel main.py web/ --onefile --noconsole --clean --icon=path/to/icon
```

I have made some changes to the program since my last compiling and have deleted a file that I will no longer use, and for some reason whenever I try to recompile into an executable I keep getting that file that I have deleted some time ago in the executable and it will not go away. When I run it from the terminal though it works fine and it does not bring up that file once

- I tried recompiling multiple times
- I tried setting --clean flag while compiling
- I tried deleting my venv and recreating it
- I tried deleting **pycache** and recompiling
- I tried clearing cache from my chrome browser
- I tried restarting my computer and then recompiling
- I tried deleting the build/ dist/ and spec file that it generates and
  recompiling multiple times

I am not sure how to get a fresh build that doesn't have that old file that I made long ago. I wanna say that the old file I made is somehow stuck in some cache and not coming out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of things and nothing worked. Then finally I cleaned out I cleaned out the cache in temp folder in windows, and then it worked and ran fine.

for me the files were stuck in/cached in

C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Temp

also be sure to clean chrome browser cache as well